# copy member of struct as key map into set container using boost copy

Tags: c++, boost, struct

Having struct below:

```
struct MixingParts{
int intPart;
double doublePart;
}
```

and std::map as follow:

```
std::map<MixingParts, std::vector<int> > MixingMap;
```

I found boost::copy very useful, I will appreciate if you please help me to only extract integer part of struct as key of the above map and insert it back to the std::set intSet;

```
boost::copy(MixingMap | boost::adoptors::map_keys(.....*Is it possible to use bind here?*...), std::inserter(intSet, intSet.begin())
```

I can only use C++98, and also any other solution which is less verbose and optimized is appreciated.

Comment: If it's not possible with Boost, how about just a simple [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with a simple function that inserts into the set?

Comment: yes your're right, I was wondering if it is possible to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boost::transform(mm, std::mem_fn(&MixingParts::intPart), 
    std::inserter(intSet, intSet.begin())));
```

Or use `copy`/`copy_range` with `transformed` adaptor

Here's an integrated live example:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e788ba45044ac74)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct MixingParts{
    int intPart;
    double doublePart;
};

using boost::adaptors::transformed;

int main() {

    std::vector<MixingParts> v { { 1,0.1 }, {2, 0.2}, {3,0.3} };

    boost::copy(v | transformed(std::mem_fn(&MixingParts::intPart)),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3
```

`boost::mem_fn` can be used too.

Comment: Problem being that [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) is C++11.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Solution being that boost::mem_fn can also be used. It's in the post. Correction. I edited that out by accident. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (MixingMap::const_iterator it = mm.begin(); it != mm.end(); ++it)
    intSet.insert(it->first.intPart);
```

It would be less verbose in C++11, but it's hardly bloated by C++98 standards.  And it's simple and optimally efficient (given the choice of data structures).